# Firestore use contains on multiple fields

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have an upcoming video games app. A game release can come out on multiple platforms. I heard that firestore is much more flexible than firebase real time database on how you can retrieve your data. I'm stuck on how can I check if my game release documents in my release collection contains the user chosen platforms, so the app can show the games coming out on his platforms.

This is what I currently have

`platforms` is a list of Integer which contains platforms ids

```
  databaseReference.collection(getRegionNode())
            .whereEqualTo("m_y", monthFilter)
            .whereArrayContains("platforms", platforms)
            .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).get().addOnCompleteListener(listener);
```

Here's an example of a game release document:

```
   1369: { 
        "src": "Images/dead.png",
        "name": "red dead 2",
        "date": 2018-10-26,
        "region": worldwide,
        "platforms": "[12, 13, 54]"
    }
```

Let's say for example, user wants to only be shown platform 12 and 13 games, I want a query that checks and retrieves all releases documents where 12 and 13 are in their ***platforms*** list. Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of the second argument passed in `.whereArrayContains("platforms", platforms)`?

Comment: a list of integer of platform ids

Comment: Can you please give me a concrete example on what you exactly pass?

Comment: my current platforms list contains platform 12 and 13

Comment: platforms.add(12) and platforms.add(13)

Comment: So the value of the seond argument that you pass is an array?

Comment: platforms is an array or a String?

Comment: an array; Arraylist<Integer> platforms

Comment: I understand. I'll write you an answer right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore Query's [whereArrayContains(String field, Object value)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#whereArrayContains(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)):

> Creates and returns a new Query with the additional filter that documents must contain the specified field, the value must be an array, and that the array must contain the provided value.

According to your comments, your `platforms` object that is passed as the second argument to this method is of type `array`. What you are actually doing, you are searching in the `platforms` property which is of type array for an array, which is not possible since the platforms array in your database contains numbers:

```
"platforms": "[12, 13, 54]"
```

And **not** arrays. A query like this:

```
databaseReference.collection(getRegionNode())
        .whereEqualTo("m_y", monthFilter)
        .whereArrayContains("platforms", 12) //Passed a number as the second argument
        .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).get().addOnCompleteListener(listener);
```

Will work fine because we are searching within the `platforms` array for a number. Please also note, if you intend to use this king of query, an `index` is required. For how to create an index, please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working)**.

Even if you using the above query, you can filter your items using only one `whereArrayContains()` method call. If you will use more than one, the following error will occur:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Query. Queries only support having a single array-contains filter.

If you need to filter on more than one platform, you'll need to change the logic of structuring your database by creating a property for each individual platform that you have and chain `whereEqualTo()` method calls. I know it sounds a little weird but this is how Cloud Firestore works.

Your schema should like this:

```
1369: { 
    "src": "Images/dead.png",
    "name": "red dead 2",
    "date": 2018-10-26,
    "region": worldwide,
    "platformsOne": 12,
    "platformsTwo": 13,
    "platformsThree": 54
}
```

To find all the games for platform `12`, `13` and `54`, you should use a query that looks like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = rootRef.
    .whereEqualTo("platformsOne", 12)
    .whereEqualTo("platformsTwo", 13)
    .whereEqualTo("platformsThree", 54);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out later today!

Comment: I can also do it like so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687714/how-to-query-documents-which-contains-a-sent-parameter-in-firestore no? Which do you think is better?

Comment: Yes you can. Both are considered better but you can do it the way you are confortable with.