# Populate autoCompleteTextView with a firebase Database

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've working on an app relying on a SQLite Database to populate an `autoCompleteTextView`, so when the user inputs some text, the app shows a list of suggestiones based on the user input.

I wanted to give the next step and Implemented a simple Firebase database to store the list of words needed for the `autoCompleteTextview`. As I'm fairly new working with Firebase,  I'm having trouble to  fetch de data from the Firebase Database.

I really don't know how to start, I suposse I should create a custom ArrayAdapter and override its methods to search the database dynamically each time the text is changed in the `AutocompleteTextView`
or search all the words in the database and put them in a single `ArrayList` to use it with the `TextView.`

Hope to hear from you and thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure your idea would work simply because firebase database does not have the query features of SQL - I don't think it is possible to get results that match what your user searches. I think you might be stuck regularly downloading a full list of keys. On the bright side, you can set up your database to simple retrieve only the keys, store those keys locally, then manage your search with the local key map. (I'm not an expert but I honestly think this is the best you can do).

Comment: *Update*, I don't have much experience with the new Firebase firestore but it might have query features that allow what you are looking for...

Comment: so you basically want to implement search using firebase database.?

Comment: I suppose  its a continuous  search because its connected to a AutocompleteTextview, from a fixed dataset or directly to the FirebaseDatabase each time the user inputs text.

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing using Firestore by creating a custom `ArrayAdapter` that listens to a Firestore query and implements `Filterable`.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product>
        implements Filterable, EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {

    private final Object mLock = new Object();
    private static final java.lang.String TAG = "Product Adapter";
    private ArrayList<Product> mProducts  = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Product> mOriginalValues;
    private ArrayFilter mFilter;
    private CharSequence mFilterPrefix;
    private Query mQuery;
    private ListenerRegistration mRegistration;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, int resource, Query query) {
        super(context, resource);
        mQuery = query;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onEvent:error", e);
            return;
        }

        for (DocumentChange change : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

            switch (change.getType()) {
                case ADDED:
                    onDocumentAdded(change);
                    break;
                case MODIFIED:
                    onDocumentModified(change);
                    break;
                case REMOVED:
                    onDocumentRemoved(change);
                    break;
            }

            if (mFilterPrefix != null) {
                getFilter().filter(mFilterPrefix);
            }
        }
    }

    public void startListening() {
        if (mQuery != null && mRegistration == null) {
            mRegistration = mQuery.addSnapshotListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void stopListening() {
        if (mRegistration != null) {
            mRegistration.remove();
            mRegistration = null;
        }

        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (mOriginalValues != null) {
                mOriginalValues.clear();
            } else {
                mProducts.clear();
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setQuery(Query query) {
        stopListening();

        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (mOriginalValues != null) {
                mOriginalValues.clear();
            }
            mProducts.clear();
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        mQuery = query;
        startListening();
    }

    protected void onDocumentAdded(DocumentChange change) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (mOriginalValues != null) {
                mOriginalValues.add(change.getNewIndex(), change.getDocument().toObject(Product.class));
            } else {
                mProducts.add(change.getNewIndex(), change.getDocument().toObject(Product.class));
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    protected void onDocumentModified(DocumentChange change) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (change.getOldIndex() == change.getNewIndex()) {
                if (mOriginalValues != null) {
                    mOriginalValues.set(change.getOldIndex(), change.getDocument().toObject(Product.class));
                } else {
                    mProducts.set(change.getOldIndex(), change.getDocument().toObject(Product.class));
                }
            } else {
                if (mOriginalValues != null) {
                    mOriginalValues.remove(change.getOldIndex());
                    mOriginalValues.add(change.getNewIndex(), change.getDocument().toObject(Product.class));
                } else {
                    mProducts.remove(change.getOldIndex());
                    mProducts.add(change.getNewIndex(), change.getDocument().toObject(Product.class));
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    protected void onDocumentRemoved(DocumentChange change) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (mOriginalValues != null) {
                mOriginalValues.remove(change.getOldIndex());
            } else {
                mProducts.remove(change.getOldIndex());
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mProducts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Product getItem(int position){
        return mProducts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView label = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        label.setText(mProducts.get(position).getName());
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        label.setText(mProducts.get(position).getName());
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public @NonNull Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ArrayFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            mFilterPrefix = prefix;

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<>(mProducts);
                }
            }

            final ArrayList<Product> values;
            synchronized (mLock) {
                values = new ArrayList<>(mOriginalValues);
            }

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                results.values = values;
                results.count = values.size();

            } else {
                final String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();
                final int count = values.size();
                final ArrayList<Product> newValues = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    final Product product = values.get(i);
                    final String valueText = product.getName().toLowerCase();

                    if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                        newValues.add(product);
                    } else {
                        final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
                        if (words.length > 1) {
                            if (words[words.length - 1].startsWith(prefixString)) {
                                newValues.add(product);
                            } else {
                                for (int j = words.length - 2; j > 0; j--) {
                                    words[j] = words[j] + " " + words[j + 1];
                                    if (words[j].startsWith(prefixString)) {
                                        newValues.add(product);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                results.values = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();

            }

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            mProducts = (ArrayList<Product>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I then set this adapter as the adapter of my `AutoCompleteTextView`. In my case I was filtering a list of objects of class `Product` by their names which I displayed in the `AutoCompleteTextView`, but you could change this just to be strings.

To be clear this method listens to the query for the entire list of documents (products in my case) and then filters them locally, rather than making a query dependent on the text typed in the `AutoCompleteTextView`. This way you don't need to make a query each time a new letter is typed and the list automatically updates if the Firestore database changes. If you wanted to instead make a new query each time the text changes you could try using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46574143/5560171).

Answer (score 0):

not exactly for autocomplete, but to search and filter item in recyclerview I used this method.

```
@Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                Query search_query = productRef.orderBy("productName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff");
                FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Product> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>().setQuery(search_query, Product.class).build();
                productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(options);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Product_List.this));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
                productAdapter.startListening();
                return false;
            }
```