# How to query a Firestore collection for a field that starts with a string

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to search for documents where a `field` starts with some `term`?

Example: finding all documents in `someCollection` where `someField` starts with "foo"
So fields with "foo", "food", "fools" would be returned but "fop", "fopp" would not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Stream streamQuery;
streamQuery = firestore.collection('someCollection')
  .where('someField', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchKey)
  .where('someField', isLessThan: searchKey +'z')
  .snapshots();
```

Comment: This works for most cases but it has a couple of limitations though. The first it only serves the english charset. Secondly, there are relevant charechters after 'z' like `~` or `{` which would not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dart adaptation of a [java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46786193/2837443)

```
final strFrontCode = term.substring(0, term.length - 1);
final strEndCode = term.characters.last;
final limit =
  strFrontCode + String.fromCharCode(strEndCode.codeUnitAt(0) + 1);

final snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('someCollection')
  .where('someField', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: term)
  .where('someField', isLessThan: limit)
  .get();
```