# Query documents in firestore that start with a string in Android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to query a firestore collection to get all documents starting with a specific string? example: to get me all the documents that start with the string "jav"

I have seen examples in others like dart but I don't know how to adapt it to java

[Firestore query documents startsWith a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573804/firestore-query-documents-startswith-a-string/46786193#46786193)

This is what I'm looking for but adapted in java.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) will help.