# swift firebase firestore isGreaterThanOrEqualTo error

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am running this code. I want users starting with 'a' to come from the database, but  starting with 'h' are coming.

```
db.collection("Users")
        .whereField("userName", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "a")
        .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Hata oluştu: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    if let userName = document.get("userName") as? String,
                       let email = document.get("email") as? String {
                        let user = Users(userName: userName, email: email)
                        self.usersList.append(user)
                    }
                }
                self.serachResultTable.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573804/firestore-query-documents-startswith-a-string ?